# Composer + VCS + Update to latest commited version

Tags: git, composer-php, vcs-tags

I want composer to update to the latest committed state of a package located in VCS (Bitbucket GIT) with the following restrictions:

- No need to increment version number in packages composer.json
- No need to increment version number in GIT using a new tag like `v1.1.0`
- Package must be installed as `dist` (without `.git` folder)

What i've already figured out:

- Bitbucket repository must be included as API (using https + oauth) instead of ssh to install `dist` package at all - works fine
- At least one version tag must exist in GIT to get a `dist` package (without `.git` folder) installed - works fine

As far as i know, just require a branch or stability would always leads to a `source` package instead of `dist`.

What is missing or how can i force composer to update the package from VCS to the state of the latest commit?

Comment: What hav you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not install from `dev-master`?

Comment: @NicoHaase Think i simply had some issues with the api or any caching. Now i got it in three different possible ways: 1) install/update from dev-master with --prefered-dist flag 2) adding "preferred-install" to project composer.json 3) Specify at least one version tag in GIT to always fall back to "dist" when package was required without flags